# Custom sound on notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to add custom sound in notification pushed by my app. I tried following code so far

**Channel code**

```
 private void createFullIntentChannel(){     
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/mysound.mp3" ) ;
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.yego.myapp.fullintent";
        String channelName = "Full Intent Channel";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setSound(sound, attributes);

        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);
    }
}
```

**Notification**

```
 Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/raw/mysound.mp3" ) ;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, "com.yego.myapp.fullintent")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_yego_logo)
                    .setContentTitle("New Booking")
                    .setContentText("From " +  pickLoc + "\n" + "To " + dropLoc)
                    .setSound(sound)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setTimeoutAfter(15000)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.payment_success_1,  getActionText(R.string.txt_accept, R.color.colorGreen), pendingAcceptIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.payment_failed_1, getActionText(R.string.txt_reject, R.color.colorRed), pendingRejectIntent)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);

    Notification incomingCallNotification = notificationBuilder.build();
    incomingCallNotification.sound = sound;
    //incomingCallNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notifId, incomingCallNotification);
```

It plays default notification sound. What i am missing ?
Also it plays default sound only once. I need it to play untill user clicked on notification or action buttons..

Please suggest

Comment: To change sound in notification you may be required to uninstall your app to alter sound settings. Also try setting `setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)` in `AudioAttributes`

Comment: @Nitish not working